# How to link the options available in a drop down menu to change the size of an image

Tags: javascript, three.js

I saw something the other day on a website that had fields on the left hand side and an image on the right hand side. When I changed an attribute lets say length it reflected on the image immediately without guiding me to a new page. I feel that is better than something predefined. I am relatively new to JavaScript so can anyone please guide me through this process on how to do it. I tried looking up on Three.js but didn't get any appropriate methods. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create 3d objects? You tagged this as three.js? You should provide more details and maybe examples of how far you've gotten / what you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an image like so:

```
<img src="suchnsuch.jpg" id="my-image" />
```

In the drop down element set the onChange attribute as so

```
<select onChange="alter_image( this.value );">
    <option value="default">Default</option>
    <option value="500">500px</option>
</select>
```

then define a Javascript function:

```
function alter_image( width ) {
    image = document.getElementById('my-image');
    image.style.width = width + "px";
}
```

When the drop down is changed it should call the alter_image function with its value and in turn alter the width property of the image.

If your image's width is defined as an attribute ( that is like so width="300px" ) then the width code should read

```
image.width = width + "px";
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2668265/patrick)'s answer I made a simple [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wU3pFasy9xmTENBt1fcF?p=preview). Is this what you need?

Code slightly modified:

```
function alter_image(width) {
  var image = document.getElementById('my-image');

  image.style.width = width != 'default' ? width + "px" : "auto";
}
```